# Postgresql 9.4 insert 100 million rows with spring & dbcp2, all data is lost

Tags: spring, postgresql, apache-commons-dbcp

I used spring's junit code(which was a convenient way for me) to insert 100 million rows into a table

[image]

insert code is like follows, DAO wraps a mybatis mapper

```
    @Transactional
public void insert10Kcommit(){
    System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { //0.1M
        ShortUrl shortUrl = new ShortUrl();
        String fullLink = SecureUtil.randomNumericString(20);
        shortUrl.setFullLink(fullLink);
        shortUrl.setPassCode(12345678L);
        shortUrl.setEffStartTime(new Date());
        shortUrl.setEffEndTime(new Date());
        shortUrlDAO.create(shortUrl);
        //ShortUrl newShortUrl = shortUrlDAO.get(shortUrl.getId());
        //assertTrue(newShortUrl.equals(shortUrl));
    }
    count += 10;
    System.out.println(count + " W is insertd. takes: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0 + " s");
}

@Test
public void insert_100M(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            insert10Kcommit();
        }
    }
}
```

the above snippet took 6 hours to complete inserting 100 millions rows into postgres 9.4, but after that, the 100 millions rows "disappear", 
this following query takes too long, it seems the 100m rows are there some where just theres something wrong with postgres. I repeated this experiment for 5 times, it all came out with the same result.
[image]

but another insert then select from psql looks right
[image]

is there anything wrong with spring or dbcp2?

can anyone help me out? many thanks.

Comment: Not at all familiar with spring, are you committing your transaction? Anyway why do you import your data in this laborious fashion. Why not COPY TO?

Comment: What a contraption to insert the rows. There is no transaction in progress so nothing will be committed. Spring uses proxies for AOP, transactionality is applied using AOP. You are doing in internal method call which doesn't pass through the proxy.

Comment: @M.Deinum the Transacational annotation was compiled by apjectj, with scope test-compile, and TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() is to see if the code is in transaction, and i'm pretty sure it's committed in a batch of 0.1 M.

Comment: @M.Deinum and even there was no transaction manager, insert will be auto committed.

Comment: No there won't be an auto commit as spring turns that off and it depends on your underlying persistence solution. Also if that is compiled with AspectJ you need to have the `@EnableTransactionManagement` set to aspectj. If you do a count how many rows are there?

Comment: @M.Deinum let's put auto commit aside, i queried count() during inserting, it increases with a step of 0.1M, after the code snippet is done, count() returns 2, and select by id take forever to return, where it returns immediately when inserting is going, you can see what's going on on the screenshot.

Comment: The fact that it is that during running doesn't mean it is actually committed, as that is the count of the current transaction... Try the count outside the transaction. I still suspect it isn't committing and rolling back.